# Calculating Principal Components from new data in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am using following code to do principal component analysis of iris data:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris() 
dat = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=['sl', 'sw', 'pl', 'pw'])

from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
stddat = scale(dat)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pc_out = pca.fit_transform(stddat)
pcdf = pd.DataFrame(data = pc_out , columns = ['PC-1', 'PC-2'])
print(pcdf.head())
```

Output:

```
       PC-1      PC-2
0 -2.264542  0.505704
1 -2.086426 -0.655405
2 -2.367950 -0.318477
3 -2.304197 -0.575368
4 -2.388777  0.674767
```

Now I want to determine PC-1 for a new set of values of 'sl', 'sw', 'pl' and 'pw', say: 4.8, 3.1, 1.3, 0.2. How can I do this? I could not find any way to do this using sklearn library.

Edit: as mentioned in comments, I can get PC values for new data with command `pca.transform(new_data)`. However, I am interested in getting variable `loadings` so that I can use these numbers to determine PC values later and from anywhere, rather than just in current environment.

By `loadings` I mean "the weight by which each standardized original variable should be multiplied to get the component score" (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis ). I cannot find a method to do this on the documentation page: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Comment: Would not `pc_out = pca.transform(new_data)` work for new data?

Comment: Additionally to above comment, you might use the class-based scaler to replicate the scaling for the new data too (again a ```transform```).

Comment: Can I get variable loadings values from pca here? I checked methods on this page but could not find it: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the `transform` function available [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/decomposition/base.py#L99):

```
    def transform(self, X):
        """Apply dimensionality reduction to X.
        X is projected on the first principal components previously extracted
        from a training set.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
            New data, where n_samples is the number of samples
            and n_features is the number of features.
        Returns
        -------
        X_new : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_components)
        Examples
        --------
        >>> import numpy as np
        >>> from sklearn.decomposition import IncrementalPCA
        >>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
        >>> ipca = IncrementalPCA(n_components=2, batch_size=3)
        >>> ipca.fit(X)
        IncrementalPCA(batch_size=3, copy=True, n_components=2, whiten=False)
        >>> ipca.transform(X) # doctest: +SKIP
        """
        check_is_fitted(self, ['mean_', 'components_'], all_or_any=all)

        X = check_array(X)
        if self.mean_ is not None:
            X = X - self.mean_
        X_transformed = np.dot(X, self.components_.T)
        if self.whiten:
            X_transformed /= np.sqrt(self.explained_variance_)
        return X_transformed
```

The variable loadings, are the components, which you get from `pca.components_`. Be sure that your `mean_` is `0` and `whiten` is `False`, and then you can simply get that matrix and use it wherever you want to transform your matrices/vectors.

Comment: `pca.components_` is what I wanted. Thanks.